# How do I insert values into a new table using SQL WHERE clause for matching?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables: Table 1 is the master table and Table 2 is a table that is refreshed monthly and truncated after. Thus, I want to write a query that inserts monthly new values from Table 2 into Table 1 using some matching fields. The columns I need to match by are country and name. Here are the tables:

[image]

How do I approach this query to get to the green table? I looked into Update and Insert Statements but could not find anything which could help.

Comment: I removed the "tsql" tag.  You have tagged incompatible databases but chosen a solution that is MySQL.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2):

How about using MERGE statement

```
MERGE INTO Table1 as Target
USING Table2 as Source
ON (target.Name = source.Name AND target.Country = source.Country)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Age = source.Age, Gender = source.Gender
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Name, Country, Age, Gender) VALUES (source.Name, source.Country, source.Age, source.Gender);
```

What the statment does is look for records in Target that match records in source by name and country. If a Match is found, the Age and Gender of the target records are update, when a match is not found, a new record is inserted in target table.

I tested this in SQL Server, but I think snowflake has the same syntax.

You can read about [MERGE statement](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html) in Snowflake documentation.

Comment: I have upvoted Sherif's answer because this is the most appropriate way to do this. However the key chosen for the merge-match does not look like a good key. It may give you more than one row to merge and will fail in that case. I am sure setting non-deterministic to true will not serve the business purpose

Comment: Of course matching by name and country is not the best solution, but the question stated explicitly "The columns I need to match by are country and name". So I used those keys to perform the match as the question posted stated.

Comment: Upvote this answer too, and well-noted @RajibDeb he should look at https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html#duplicate-join-behavior section to better mitigate errors

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake syntax

```
    UPDATE
        table1 AS TA
    SET
        TA.Age = TB.Age
    FROM (SELECT TA1.country, TB1.country, TA1.name, TB1.name, TB1.Age 
            FROM table1 AS TA1 
            INNER JOIN table2 AS TB1
                ON (TA1.country = TB1.country AND TA1.name= TB1.name)) TB
    WHERE TA.country = TB.country
```

And MySql

```
    UPDATE
        table1 AS TA
        INNER JOIN table2 AS TB
            ON TA.country = TB.country
            AND TA.name= TB.name
    SET
        TA.Age = TB.Age;
```

Comment: Note: *The columns I need to match by are country **and name** *

Comment: added condition => ON TA.country = TB.country AND TA.name= TB.name.

Comment: @Deep error: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 8 unexpected 'JOIN'.. I am using Snowflake. What could that be due to?

Comment: @cesarteaserr Try this one => 
UPDATE
    table1 AS TA
SET
    TA.Age = TB.Age
FROM (SELECT TA1.country, TB1.country, TA1.name, TB1.name, TB1.Age 
  FROM table1 AS TA1 
  INNER JOIN table2 AS TB1
   ON (TA1.country = TB1.country AND TA1.name= TB1.name)) TB
WHERE TA.country = TB.country

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have to only update the age column in the table1.

```
update table1 set AGE=(select distinct age from table2 t2 where t2.COUNTRY=table1.COUNTRY and t2.NAME=table1.NAME);
```

or

```
 UPDATE table1 SET table1.age = table2.age FROM table1 , table2 where table1.country = table2.country and table1.name = table2.name
```

Comment: error: unsupported sub-query. I am using Snowflake.

Comment: This worked well in Postgres, Oracle, and SQL server, try the second query, I have edited my entry.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake syntax is a bit different here.  Something like this should work:

```
UPDATE table1 TA
SET TA.Age = TB.Age
FROM table2 TB
WHERE TA.country = TB.country
  AND TA.name = TB.name;
```

As a note, the documentation on Snowflake is excellent.  The syntax for this is located here:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/update.html